# How to give unique name to every element in a Seq of Modules in the final Verilog file

Tags: chisel

I looking for advice on how give unique name to each element of a Seq in the final generated Verilog file.

for example if I have Seq of fifos:

```
val fifos = Seq.fill(6)(Module(new Fifo(32, 2, true)))
```

in the generated Verilog I get 6 instances Fifo_0,Fif0_1,..,Fifo_5.
How do I give them a unique name ?

Comment: When you says «a unique name» you ask about an array no ? You want a instances of type : Fifo[0], Fifo[1], ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply suggest name each element of the `Seq`

`fifos(0).suggestName("FirstFifo")
fifos(1).suggestName("SecondFifo")`